# Dojo accordion container programatically display grid when collapsed

Tags: dojo, accordion, pane

I started learning Dojo yesterday, so please excuse my ignorance...

My expectation is to create an accordion dynamically and show a grid in the content pane of the accordion. To do that I create the accordion widget with 2 content panes and when the content pane is onShow handled, I create a custom widget and add to the content pane (this is a necessity, i.e., I cannot add a data grid directly). Once the custom grid is created it creates a timer and on the timer's elapse I populate the grid and show it.

Now, if you run this in a browser (of course with dojo in the right path), you would notice after about 8 seconds timeout, the accordion pane shows the grid (in a clumsy way, which I still need to figure why, any help would be great). But then:

If I open the second pane immediately (well within 8 seconds) after refresh and keep first pane closed until after 8 seconds and then open the first pane, nothing seems to be present. Could Dojo experts kindly help me understand why? Thanks!

```
<html>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
            @import "dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/layout/AccordionContainer.css";
            @import "dojo/resources/dojo.css"
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        /*
            The source is organized like this:
                head;
                script;
                    timer proc;
                    grid widget;
                        constructor, postCreate, onElapse method where the grid is populated.
                    Accordion widget:
                        construct, postCreate panes are created and added.
        */

        // Mock backend
        var timerThis = undefined;
        function onElapse()
        {
            timerThis.onElapse();
        }

        // Grid Widget declaration.
        dojo.provide("widgets.GridWidget");
        dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
        dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
        dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
        dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");

        // Grid widget class.
        dojo.declare("widgets.GridWidget", [ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated ], {

            // Members
            templateString : '<div id="${id}" dojoAttachPoint="widgets_GridWidget"></div>',
            srcNodeRef : null,
            grid : null,
            timer : null,

            // Constructor
            constructor : function(params, srcNodeRef)
            {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.id = "myUniqueId";
                this.srcNodeRef = srcNodeRef;

                // Copy this so timer onElapse() can access.
                timerThis = this;
                this.timer = setTimeout("onElapse()", 8000);
            },

            // Member invoked from global onElapse.
            onElapse : function()
            {
                var layout =
                [
                    { name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 'auto' },
                    { name: 'Color', field: 'color', width: 'auto' }
                ];

                var store =
                {
                    data :
                    {
                        items :
                        [
                            { name : 'John Doe', color: 'green' },
                            { name : 'Jane Doe', color: 'red' }
                        ]
                    }
                };

                // Create a grid and startup.
                this.grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                    store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(store),
                    clientSort: true,
                    rowSelector: '20px',
                    structure: layout
                }, this.srcNodeRef);
                this.widgets_GridWidget.appendChild(this.grid.domNode);
                this.grid.startup();
            }
        });

                // Create an accordion container that will display the grid in one of its pane.
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.declare("widgets.AccordionWidget", [ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated ],
        {
            templateString : '<div id="AccordionWidget" dojoAttachPoint="widgets_AccordionWidget"></div>',
            srcNodeRef : null,
            constructor : function(params, srcNodeRef)
            {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                this.srcNodeRef = srcNodeRef;
            },
            postCreate : function()
            {
                this.inherited(arguments);

                var container = new dijit.layout.AccordionContainer({
                        style : "height: 100px"
                    },
                    this.widgets_AccordionWidget.id + "_Container");


                var panes =
                [
                    new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "First pane"
                    }),
                    new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        title: "Second pane"
                    })
                ];
                container.addChild(panes[0]);
                container.addChild(panes[1]);

                this.widgets_AccordionWidget.appendChild(container.domNode);
                // Scope closure
                {
                    var pane = panes[0];
                    // var pane = panes[1];
                    var wdg = undefined;
                    pane.set("onShow",
                        function()
                        {
                            if (wdg === undefined)
                            {
                                wdg = new widgets.GridWidget({}, pane.id + "_1");
                                wdg.placeAt(pane.domNode);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                this.widgets_AccordionWidget.appendChild(container.domNode);
                container.startup();
            }
        });

        dojo.addOnLoad(function()
        {
            dojo.require('dojo.parser');
        });

        dojo.ready(function()
        {
            dojo.parser.parse();
            var wdg = new widgets.AccordionWidget({}, dojo.byId("root"));
        });

    </script>
    <body class="tundra"> 
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this copy paste code..
im diplaying the grid on show of the accordian pane. One thing i could not achive is that i could not resize the pane according to the grid height.

Please let me know if this useful.
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";   
</style>        
<script src="djlib/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>   
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="djlib/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" type="text/css" />
<body class="claro">
    <div id="root" ></div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

<script>            
    dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
    dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionPane");
    dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');

    dojo.declare("widgets.Ackordian", [ dijit.layout.AccordionContainer ], {
        style:'height:300px',
        id:'Ackordian1',
        postCreate:function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.startup();
            this.addChild(
                new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({
                    //content : "<p>HI There2</p>",
                    style:'height:100px',
                    title:'H!',
                    widgetsInTemplate:true
                })
            )
            this.addChild(
                new dijit.layout.AccordionPane({
                    style:'height:100px',
                    //content : "<p>HI There2</p>",
                    title:'HI2'

                })
            )                   
            dojo.forEach(this.getChildren(),function(pane,indx){

                dojo.mixin(pane,{
                    onShow:function(){
                        if(!pane.grid){                         
                            pane.grid = getGrid();
                            pane.setContent(pane.grid.domNode);
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });

    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        new widgets.Ackordian({}).placeAt('root');              
    })
    function getGrid(layout,str){
        var layout =
            [
                { name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 'auto' },
                { name: 'Color', field: 'color', width: 'auto' }
            ];

            var str =
            {
                data :
                {
                    items :
                    [
                        { name : 'John Doe', color: 'green' },
                        { name : 'Jane Doe', color: 'red' }
                    ],
                    identifier:'color',
                    label:'name'
                }

            };
        return new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            style:'height:100px',
            store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(str),
            clientSort: true,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            structure: layout
        })

    }
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Raj appreciate your answer, found that I had to specify height/width with style. That solved the problem, appreciate your answer again! Thanks!